# Анализ CSV файла, улучшение, Python

Tags: python, csv, анализ

Вот код программы , которая считывает из CSV файла(прикреплен скрин) информацию об автомобилях. Задание такое: пользователь вводит дату, и надо вывести, отсортировав по имени, всю информацию о машинах , которые в данное время находятся на станции(1ая дата - прибытие, 2ая - отбытие) . Я сделал лишь возможность вывода по дате прибытия, поможете с заданием?(обязательно нужно использовать словарь)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
d = {}
date1 =[]
cars=[]
date2 = input('Введите дату, в формате: **.**.****') 
with open('cars.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:                               
         line = line.split(';')
         d[int(line.pop(0))] = line    
         if line[-2] not in date1:
            date1.append(line[-2])  
    for i in range(1, len(d)+1):           
    if date2 in d[i]:                   
        qwe = d[i]                  
        cars.append(qwe[0])
cars.sort()
if len(ships)>0: 
    for i in cars:
        for c in range(1, len(d)+1):
            if i in d.get(c,''):
                print(d[c])         
else:
    print('Нет сведений об автомобилях')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких задач идеально подходит модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

dt = '2019-01-01'

res = (pd.read_csv('d:/temp/data.csv', header=None, sep=';',
                   names=['ID','Car','From','To'],
                   parse_dates=['From','To'])
         .query("From <= @dt <= To")
         .sort_values('Car'))

print(res)
```

результат:

```
  ID       Car        From          To
2  3     Гуков  2019-01-01  2019-12-12
4  5     Джони  2018-01-11  2019-12-12
6  7        На  2018-12-15  2019-05-30
5  б       Они  2019-01-01  2019-09-21
1  2   Разящий  2018-12-15  2019-01-15
8  9  Стреляй!  2019-01-01  2019-09-21
```

исходный CSV (пришлось использовать распознавалку текста, чтобы получить данные из картинки):

```
1;Кексик;2018-01-11;2018-11-22
2;Разящий;2018-12-15;2019-01-15
3;Гуков;2019-01-01;2019-12-12
4;По-утрам;2017-03-18;2017-09-21
5;Джони;2018-01-11;2019-12-12
б;Они;2019-01-01;2019-09-21
7;На;2018-12-15;2019-05-30
8;Деревьях;2018-12-15;2018-12-17
9;Стреляй!;2019-01-01;2019-09-21
10;Почему;2018-01-11;2018-02-11
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> как получить возможность вывода "нету информации", в случае отсутствия
>   даты в промежутке

```
if not res.empty:
    print(res)
else:
    print('Нету информации')
```

Comment: Спасибо, и правда удобно.

Comment: Оуу, прошу прощения, а не подскажите, как в сием чуде получить возможность вывода "нету информации", в случае отсутствия даты в промежутке, пробовал так :
`if dt not in res:
    print('Нету информации')
else:
    print(res)`
Но так не рабоет...

Comment: @alexh1n11, дополнил ответ...